# Dynamic modal within a loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a dynamic modal within a loop. It works fine besides the fact that the modal content is the same as the last modal in the loop for every modal. That means that if I open the first modal, the content inside will be the content that's suppose to be only  on the last one. Same thing if I open the second one. I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
{% for dr in results %}

    <button id="myBtn{{dr.id}}">More Info</button>
    <div id="myModal{{dr.id}}" class="modal">

      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p class="modal-info"> Name: {{dr.driver__first_name}} </p>
        <p class="modal-info"> Phone number: {{dr.driver__phone_number}}</p>
        <p class="modal-info">Bus Type: </p>
        <p class="modal-info">License Plate:</p>

      </div>

    </div>

</div>      


    <script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal{{dr.id}}");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn{{dr.id}}");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>


{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Try storing the content (name and phone_number) in an array then for each modal generated, grant it an id value, which corresponds to the index within the array and when the modal button is clicked, the name and phone_numbers would be accessed from the array with the index as the id.

Comment: So that would be done outside of my current for loop?